# Extracting entry positions in R

Tags: r

I have a vector, A, with lots of entries, for example

```
1 4 2 5 6 7 8 3 5
```

I want to get a list of all the positions of entries in that vector that are in [2,6], so id like the output to be

```
2 3 4 5 8 9
```

please help

Comment: Try `which` (`?which`)

Comment: `a<-c(1,4,2,5,6,7,8,3,5);which(a %in% 2:6, arr.ind = T)`

Comment: Take a look at http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%`

```
which(v1 %in% 2:6)
```